# "Fixing too many indices for array"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I am trying to do an array comparison. But when I am trying to do it, I get the error,"too many indices for array". I couldn't get it right.

I have tried changing the range in my for loop but I still get the same error. I couldn't think of any other reason why this could happen.

```
thresholdvalue1=(xpatient-sd_healthy)*10
thresholdvalue2=(((xhealthy+sd_patient))*10)
thresholdlist=[]
TP=[]
FP=[]
TN=[]
FN=[]
Ahealthy=np.random.randint(10,size=(1000,50))
Apatient=np.random.randint(10,size=(1000,50))
def thresholding(A,B): 
    for i in range(A,B):
        thresholdlist.append(i)
        i+=1
def newlist():
    thresholdarray=np.asarray(thresholdlist)
    thedivisor=10
    newarray=(thresholdarray/thedivisor)
    print(newarray)
    for n in range(0,51):
        if Apatient[:,n]>=newarray[:,n]:
            TP.append(Apatient[:,n])
        elif Ahealthy[:,n]>=newarray[:,n]:
            FP.append(Ahealthy[:,n])
        elif Apatient[:,n]<=newarray[:,n]:
            TN.append(Apatient[:,n])
        else:
            FN.append(Ahealthy[:,n])

thresholding(thresholdvalue1,thresholdvalue2+1)
newlist()
```

As you can see I am trying to compare each column of the matrices to a threshold value. And the second for loop is about that comparison. At the end I want to have 4 lists with the conditioned values.

Comment: your "newarray" is one dimensional while you try to use it two dimensional

Comment: Oh, I got it now, thanks a lot